# XML and accented characters

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, xquery, non-ascii-characters

I'm extracting data from this [website](http://www.worldfootball.net/). I do use UTF-8 for my xml, the same charset for the website so I don't really understand why data arent encoded correctly.

For example, from [this page](http://www.worldfootball.net/spieler_profil/astrit-ajdarevic/) I'm getting `Astrit AjdareviÄ&#135;` instead of `Astrit Ajdarević`, and `Standard LiÃ¨ge` instead of `Standard Liège` and so on...

Details: **extracting how?**

Well, I'm using [WebHarvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/) wich transform the html page into valid xml before parsing it.

So, for the example above, I use `//div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()` to get `Astrit AjdareviÄ&#135;` and `//*[@id="site"]//div[contains(./div/h2, 'Spieler')]//tbody/tr[2]/td[position()=3]` to get `Standard LiÃ¨ge`...

I hope this answers your questions :)

---

**Solution:**

```
<html-to-xml>
     <http url="${link}" charset="utf-8"/>
</html-to-xml>
```

Thanks to mactwixs <3

Comment: Your question lacks important details. How do you proceed?

Comment: I added some details. I hope it helps clarify the problem...

Comment: How do you view Astrit AjdareviÄ&#135; ? What characters does the viewer understand

Comment: I use a script with the given xpath to get my data and store it in an xml... when I open my xml (using sublime or gedit), I see `Astrit AjdareviÄ&#135;` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set UTF-8 as default in your Web-Harvest Config file otherwise it will not be set as default. Also ensure you have latest version of Web-Harvest (2.1)

See the following:

[Manual - Config](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php)

[Manual - HTTP Config](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#http)

[Similar Support    Request](http://sourceforge.net/p/web-harvest/discussion/591299/thread/9a6328bb/)

The [HTML that your browser resolves](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm) will also need:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

If non of that works I suggest raising a support request on sourceforge.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, I just added `charset="utf-8"` when I retrieve the web page, and it worked like a charm... I added the full query to the main post for those who may have the same problem in the future :)

Comment: Great stuff - glad to have helped. Seems one or two had the same issue on WH Forums too.